# ¿Es posible especificar una variable de una clase como parámetro de una función?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber si se puede reutilizar una función (en este caso de reordenación alfabética) para objetos de distintas clases, especificando la variable como parámetro de la función.

Por ejemplo, si tengo estas dos clases:

```
public class Cliente{  
    public String nombre;
}

public class Producto{
    public String nombre;
    String proveedor;
}
```

Y tengo una función para ordenar alfabéticamente los clientes de la siguiente forma:

```
public void ordenaAlfabeticamente(ArrayList <Cliente> listaClientes) throws Exception{
    Collator esCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
    String spanishRules = ((RuleBasedCollator) esCollator).getRules();

    RuleBasedCollator collate = new RuleBasedCollator(spanishRules);

    Collections.sort(listaClientes, new Comparator<Cliente>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Cliente cliente1, Cliente cliente2) {

            String nombre1= cliente1.nombre();
            String nombre2= cliente1.nombre();

            return collate.compare(nombre1, nombre2);
        }
    });
}
```

El asunto es que pasar cualquier tipo de objeto sé que puedo especificando en vez de cliente `Object`, pero no me serviría de nada si no puedo especificar a qué parámetro ha de acceder.

¿Existe alguna forma posible de hacer algo como esto?

```
public void ordenaAlfabeticamente(ArrayList <Object> listaObjetos, Object.String);
```

Comment: ¿Cual versión de Java usas?

Comment: Algo así como con Reflection https://mejorenjava.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/reflexion-en-java/

Comment: @sstan uso el 8

Comment: @Garrizano tampoco conocía Reflection, gracias por tu respuesta, siempre es interesante aprender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tienes Java 8+, una buena manera elegante de hacerlo sin tener que recurrir al uso de reflexión (que puede dejar tu código muy frágil), es usando una combinación de [genéricos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) y [expresiones lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

La idea es que cambies tu parámetro *lista* para que sea genérico (`ArrayList<T>`). Y para especificar cual campo de la clase `T` deseas usar para ordenar las entidades, puedes aceptar esa información usando el *functional interface* [`java.util.function.Function<T,R>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

Tu método `ordenaAlfabeticamente` se parecería entonces a esto:

```
public <T> void ordenaAlfabeticamente(ArrayList<T> listaEntidades, Function<T, String> getProperty) throws Exception {
    Collator esCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
    String spanishRules = ((RuleBasedCollator) esCollator).getRules();

    RuleBasedCollator collate = new RuleBasedCollator(spanishRules);

    Collections.sort(listaEntidades, (T cliente1, T cliente2) -> {
        String nombre1 = getProperty.apply(cliente1);
        String nombre2 = getProperty.apply(cliente2);

        return collate.compare(nombre1, nombre2);
    });
}
```

Y las llamadas al método se parecerían a esto:

```
ordenaAlfabeticamente(listaClientes, c -> c.nombre);
ordenaAlfabeticamente(listaProductos, p -> p.nombre);
ordenaAlfabeticamente(listaProductos, p -> p.proveedor);
```

Te dejo un enlace para que veas una demostración completa en vivo: [**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/DAGFV3396).

**Edición: Si usas una versión anterior a Java 8**

Si estás usando una versión anterior a Java 8, entonces no puedes usar los lambdas, ni tampoco existe la interfaz `java.util.function.Function<T,R>`.

Aun así, es posible usar la misma idea sin las expresiones lambda. Pero el código no es tan elegante y compacto en ese caso.

Para que funcione, necesitas crear tu propia interfaz `Function<T, R>` o algo equivalente:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}
```

El método `ordenaAlfabeticamente` casi no cambia (solo que tengo que quitar una expresión lambda):

```
public <T> void ordenaAlfabeticamente(ArrayList<T> listaEntidades, Function<T, String> getProperty) throws Exception {
    Collator esCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
    String spanishRules = ((RuleBasedCollator) esCollator).getRules();

    RuleBasedCollator collate = new RuleBasedCollator(spanishRules);

    Collections.sort(listaEntidades, new Comparator<T>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(T cliente1, T cliente2) {
            String nombre1 = getProperty.apply(cliente1);
            String nombre2 = getProperty.apply(cliente2);

            return collate.compare(nombre1, nombre2);
        }
    });
}
```

Y finalmente, la parte que pierde su elegancia es en las llamadas al método (porque no puedo usar lambdas):

```
ordenaAlfabeticamente(
    listaClientes, 
    new Function<Cliente, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Cliente cliente) {
            return cliente.nombre;
        }
    });

ordenaAlfabeticamente(
    listaProductos, 
    new Function<Producto, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Producto producto) {
            return producto.nombre;
        }
    });

ordenaAlfabeticamente(
    listaProductos, 
    new Function<Producto, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Producto producto) {
            return producto.proveedor;
        }
    });
```

Te dejo otro enlace para que veas una demostración pre-Java 8 en vivo: [**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/DAW66157).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha sido la mejor respuesta que he visto en toda mi vida en StackOverflow!! Eres el amo, te daría 1000 puntos si pudiese.